# Combining Data from Two MYSQL Tables in Across Columns

Tags: php, mysql, join

I've searched around quite a bit but couldn't find an answer. Perhaps I'm not using the right keywords, but I finally decided to just ask. Sorry if this has been asked before and I couldn't find it.

Here's my situation:

I have a school. One MYSQL table has a list of students, with a auto_increment id. 
Another table has a list of classes, which has multiple columns for multiple students. Currently I have the students registered in the class table using the ids from the first column.

I want to display a list of class and have each member id from the class table call the name from the student table.

I know how to do this with only one column of student ids using a mysql join.

However, I want to get the name for each member1, member2, member3, etc and display them.

Is this possible?

Other question, is there a better way to do this? For example, I could just store the class table data by name and output that directly, then when I needed to use the SELECT x,y,z FROM db WHERE member1 = name?

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Thoughts?  Your class table is poorly organized.  You should basically have two columns, `classId` and `StudentId`, not multiple columns for each student.

Comment: Sarcasm not withstanding, thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding columns per student is a horrible architecture for so many reason. 
What you need to do is have a student table, with a primary key for each student. A class table with a primary key for each class.

Then you have a registration table with each row having a foreign key to one student and a foreign key to one class. This table basically is your join table for a many to many relationship. A student can enroll in multiple classes and of course a class can have multiple students.

A query on the registration table with a specific classId will give you all students registered for a given class. A query on the registration table with a specific studentId will give you all classes a specific student is registered for.

If you are looking to retrieve the names of students or classes you can do a join on the respective table (read up on inner joins for this).

Another approach, which I use in my applications to write MySQL stored functions. 
For example, fn_lookupStudentName(studentId int) would be a function that takes a studentId and returns a student's name. Similarly for classes.

With those functions you would not need to do explicit joins in your queries, and your queries will not miss data if for some reason you delete rows from either the student or the class tables. Separately, I do not believe you should ever do a hard delete of rows from your database, but instead do a soft delete with an isDeleted column or similar approach.

I purposefully did not put any code in the answer to encourage to read up on the ideas above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your ideas. As you can tell I am neither a professional nor very experienced and knew the answer had to be simpler than I was imagining it from my uneducated standpoint. As you suggest I will do my best to research such things and make a better table system.

Comment: With the short amount of research I've done, I've been able to dreg up the information I need using three tables as you suggest and a two joins. My query looks like this:SELECT StudentDB.first_name, StudentDB.last_name, ClassDB.class_title, ClassDB.class_level, ClassDB.day, ClassDB.time, ClassDB.teacher, RegDB.studentid FROM ClassDB INNER JOIN RegDB ON ClassDB.classID = RegDB.classid JOIN StudentDB ON StudentDB.studentID = RegDB.studentid WHERE ClassDB.day = '$day' Is this the sort of solution you were suggesting?

Comment: Yes Benjamin, that's a great start and much improved from your original post, best of luck.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll do my best.